# C linux signals and functions

Tags: c, linux, function, event-handling, signals

I got this issue, which I will simplify below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGALRM, &INThandler);

    //get menu options which Im not going to put here
    game(...stuff...);
}

void game(..stuff...) {
    //do the game stuff AND set an alarm()
}

void INThandler(int sig) {
    system("clear");
    printf("Time is up!\n");
    //I WANT game() TO STOP WHICH WILL EXIT TO MAIN WHERE MORE STUFF IS HAPPENING
}
```

In game() I have

```
while(counter <= amount)
```

So I wanted to pass the variables counter and amount into INThandler so I could change them so the condition is false, however INThandler is only called when the alarm is at 0 and is not called with parameters. game() continues and I don't want it to. If there is a better way please tell me.

Comment: What is the issue ? How to pass paramets or the function being called only once ?

Comment: Note that you can safely call only async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler.  [See the POSIX standard for an explanation and the specified list of functions that can be called](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03).  And `system()` and `printf()` are *not* async-signal-safe.  Additionally, Linux falls short of POSIX compliance in that `fork()` on Linux is not async-signal-safe so you have to use `posix_spawn()` to be fully safe, although for single-threaded applications there's not likely to be a problem with `fork()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use global variables for counter and amount ?

Answer (score 0):

When a function is called and that function has variables in it, those variables are allocated on the stack. If you define a global variable, it will be instead be allocated as the program loads. Your signal handler should have access to those variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //Also include this, needed for exit(returncode)

int counter; //Not inside any function
int amount;  //All functions may access these

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGALRM, &INThandler); 

    //get menu options which Im not going to put here
    game(...stuff...);
}

void game(..stuff...) {
    //do the game stuff AND set an alarm()
}

void INThandler(int sig) {
    //Do stuff with counter and amount
    //system("clear"); I recommend that you do not use system to clear the screen, system(command) is inefficient.
    printf("\033[H\033[JTime is up!\n");
    //Do that extra stuff you want to do in main here, then
    exit(0);
}
```

Another note: according to signal(2) in the Linux programming manual:

> The only portable use of signal() is to set a signal's disposition to
>   SIG_DFL or SIG_IGN. The semantics when using signal() to establish a
>   signal handler vary across systems (and POSIX.1 explicitly permits
>   this variation); do not use it for this purpose.
>
> POSIX.1 solved the portability mess by specifying sigaction(2), which
>   provides explicit control of the semantics when a signal handler is
>   invoked; use that interface instead of signal().

To register a signal handler using sigaction,

```
#include <signal.h>

int main(){
    const struct sigaction saSIGALRM = {
        .sa_handler = mySignalHandler, //replace this with your signal handler, it takes the same parameters as using signal()
    };
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &saSIGALRM, 0);
}
```

It's simpler than it looks. Remember, computers are slow today because of inefficient programming. Please, please, please, for efficient programs, use this instead.

[Click here for more cool things sigaction can do, along with why not to use signal()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)